# Parse .olk15Message file in python on Mac

Tags: python, macos, outlook

I'm trying to parse email files with the extension .olk15Message, which are files produced by Outlook 2016 on Mac. The files are some sort of binary format, so it's not obvious how to read from them.

I've read in another thread that using the `pypiwin32` package may help, but I'm not sure it's possible to install it on Mac OS X.

Has anyone tried to do this, and if so what packages/tricks did you use?

Answer (score 1):

There is a tool https://github.com/glymphie/UBF8T346G9Parser that is meant for exporting entire email bodies from Mac's Outlook, but it also includes a nifty way of slicing the necessary content out of the olk15message body.

See https://github.com/glymphie/UBF8T346G9Parser/blob/main/src/olk15parser/parser.py for details